# replace an empty string for exiv2 output

Tags: linux, shell, exiv2

I'm trying to collect image metadata using exiv2 tool.

I do
`exiv2 -q -K Xmp.photoshop.Credit image.jpg`
if image haven't any value for such field, I don't get anything in the console.
How I can replace an empty output by some stub like 'empty' word?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can replace it with code below:

```
exiv2 -q -K Xmp.photoshop.Credit -g Xmp.photoshop.Credit=empty image.jpg
```

Comment: this give error 'empty: Failed to open the file'

Comment: Couldn't find the file where you run exiv2, are you sure you wrote the path of the file correctly?

Comment: yes, I've run this script in the same directory as I run working exiv2 -q -K Xmp.photoshop.Credit image.jpg with empty output.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error now, but unfortunately it prints the same empty output as my script

Comment: I'm thinking but i don't know why you are seeing this result.